# this.setState not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state-saving

I don't know why but after I log in and then log out I am unable to switch between the signup and login panel in "`AuthForm.jsx`" the "`this.setState`" will not work. I have expounded on the code breaking into somany pieces to see where it could go wrong.

Console logs before login:

```
authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed"
authToggleDisplaySignUp true {displaySignUp: false}
authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed"
authToggleDisplaySignUp true {displaySignUp: true}
authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed"
authToggleDisplaySignUp true {displaySignUp: false}
authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed"
authToggleDisplaySignUp true {displaySignUp: true}
```

Console logs after login:

```
authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed
authToggleDisplaySignUp true {displaySignUp: true}
authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed
authToggleDisplaySignUp true {displaySignUp: true}
authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed
authToggleDisplaySignUp true {displaySignUp: true}
```

This is the "Root.jsx"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Home from "./Home.jsx";
import AuthForm from "./AuthForm/AuthForm.jsx";
import { fetchAuthenticated } from "../actions/account.js";     

class Root extends Component {
  state = {
    displaySignUp: false
  };

  authToggleDisplaySignUp = () => {
    console.log("authToggleDisplaySignUp pressed");
    this.setState(
      {
        displaySignUp: !this.state.displaySignUp
      },
      () => {
        console.log("authToggleDisplaySignUp true", this.state);
      }
     );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.account.loggedIn && !this.state.displaySignUp) {
      return <Home authToggleDisplaySignUp={this.authToggleDisplaySignUp} />;
    } else {
      return (
        <AuthForm
          displaySignUp={this.state.displaySignUp}
          authToggleDisplaySignUp={this.authToggleDisplaySignUp}
        />
      );
    }
  }
}
export default connect(
  ({ account }) => ({ account }),
  { fetchAuthenticated }
)(Root);
```

This is the AuthForm.jsx

```
import React, { Component, lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import Login from "./Login.jsx";
import Loading from "../Loading.jsx";
import Misc from "../Misc.jsx";
import "../css/AuthForm.css";

const SignUp = lazy(() => import("./SignUp.jsx"));

class AuthForm extends Component {
  validateEmail = email => {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
  };

  get loginSignup() {
    if (!this.props.displaySignUp) {
      return (
        <Login
          validateEmail={this.validateEmail}
          toggleDisplaySignUp={this.props.authToggleDisplaySignUp}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <SignUp
            validateEmail={this.validateEmail}
            toggleDisplaySignUp={this.props.authToggleDisplaySignUp}
          />
        </Suspense>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.displaySignUpState}
        <div className="holder">
          <div className="leftSide" />
          <div className="rightSide">
            {this.loginSignup}
            <Misc />
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthForm;
```

Home.jsx

```
import React, { Component, lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "./Loading.jsx";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchInfo } from "../actions/accountInfo.js";
import history from "../history.js";

// Lazy Loading Components
const AccountInfo = lazy(AccountInfo => import("./AccountInfo.jsx"));
const NavBar = lazy(NavBar => import("./NavBar.jsx"));
const Upload = lazy(Upload => import("./Upload.jsx"));

class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchInfo();
    this.checkStatus();
  }

  checkStatus = () => {
    if (!this.props.account.loggedIn) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <NavBar />
        </Suspense>
        <p>Home Page</p>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <AccountInfo accountInfo={this.props.accountInfo} />
        </Suspense>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <Upload />
        </Suspense>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ accountInfo, account }) => ({ accountInfo, account }),
  { fetchInfo }
)(Home);
```

I used "props tunneling" to send the `toggleDisplaySignUp` down to the the login and signup components they are just 2 layers down, I actually didn't use `toggleDisplaySignUp` in The "`Home.jsx`" I just sent it there for testing something which didn't work out. I have removed it.

Login.jsx

```
<h4 onClick={this.props.toggleDisplaySignUp}>
   <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
</h4>
```

SignUp.jsx

```
<h4 onClick={this.props.toggleDisplaySignUp}>
   <a href="#">Login</a>
</h4>
```

Just incase here is the Logout function it just makes a GET request to the server and changes the `this.props.account.loggedIn` to false

```
class Logout extends Component {
  reRoute = () => {
    this.props.logout();
  };

  render() {
    return (

      <button onClick={this.reRoute}>Log Out</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some information about how the `toggleDisplaySignUp` function is being used inside of the Login and Signup and Home components?

Comment: Can you please share your Home file?

Comment: Try to change the function from `get loginSignup(){}` in AuthForm to `loginSignup = () => {}`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `setState()` is asynchronous. 
If you must perform updates only after the components state is updated, use `setState()`'s second parameter.

```
setState(
  { name: "Michael" },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);
```

Please check out:

- [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
- [setState takes a callback](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296)

Comment: The console.log callback after the setState isn't the issue I am having, Thank you though. I used the callback function because I know it is async so it would only occur after the setState so I could check the state if it was changed or not and that it the issue the state will stop taking changes after I log in and log out

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what i did but the code is working now. I removed `fetchAuthenticated` from `Root.jsx` and BOOM magic. I will be reviewing my Git changes and provide more details as a comment to this answer. Thank you everyone.